# Why do I have an error? I am very new and I am trying to make a simple shield/restriction app

Tags: swift, debugging

I am making a simple shield app for my kid and I am new to Swift I apologize in advance for the bad code. I learned this from a tutorial on Youtube.

```
import Foundation
import FamilyControls
import DeviceActivity
import ManagedSettings
import SwiftUI

extension DeviceActivityName {
    static let daily = Self("daily")
}

struct Testing_SwiftUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        class MyMonitor: DeviceActivityMonitor {
            let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
           
            override func intervalDidStart(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
                
                self.superBS_Start()
```

//It returns MyModel() cannot be found within the scope.

```
                let model = MyModel()
                let applications = model.selectionToDiscourage.applications
                store.shield.applications = applications?.isEmpty ? nil : applications
            }
            
            override func intervalDidEnd(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
                
                self.superBS_End()
                store.shield.applications = nil
            }
        }
        func superBS_Start(){
            super.intervalDidStart(for: activity)
        }
        func superBS_End(){
            super.intervalDidEnd(for: activity)
        }
                
        let schedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(
            intervalStart: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0),
            intervalEnd: DateComponents(hour:23, minute: 59),
            repeats: true
        )
        
        let center = DeviceActivityCenter()
        try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)
```

//It returns MyModel() cannot be found within the scope.

```
        @StateObject var model = MyModel()
        @State var isPresented = false
        
        var body: some View {
            Button ("Select Apps to Discourage"){
                isPresented = true
            }
            .familyActivityPicker(isPresented: $isPresented,
                                  selection: $model.selectionToDisourage)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why it isn't in the scope. I apologize I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

When they talk about 'extensions', theyre talking about [app extensions](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/), not Swift extensions. Go into the bundle in XCode and add a `DeviceActivityMonitor` extension, and run the subclassing there.